# How do I access sub dictionary values in nested json file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I try to access sub dictionary in nested json file. How do I correctly loop over this data structure? I can access high-level keys without a problem, but I cannot figure out a way to access sub dictionary within one of the keys.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
with open('all.json') as access_json:
    read_content = json.load(access_json)
read_content.keys()
Out[20]: dict_keys(['documents', 'see', 'rated', 'name', 'points', 'slug', 'logo'])
```

This I can access without any problems

```
points_list = read_content['points']
type(points_list)
Out[20]: dict
```

Then, I can access individual key

```
points_list['tosdr/review/stackoverflow.com']
```

Which presents me with

```
[{'description': 'Generated through the annotate view',
  'discussion': 'https://edit.tosdr.org/points/6166',
  'id': '6166',
  'point': 'bad',
  'privacyRelated': True,
  'score': 70,
  'title': 'This service allows tracking via third-party cookies for purposes including targeted advertising.'},
 {'description': 'Generated through the annotate view',
  'discussion': 'https://edit.tosdr.org/points/6131',
  'id': '6131',
  'point': 'bad',
  'score': 60,
  'title': 'You agree to defend, indemnify, and hold the service harmless in case of a claim related to your use of the service'}]
```

Now, I can access Interesting values, like this

```
points_list['tosdr/review/stackoverflow.com'][1]['title']
Out[30]: 'You agree to defend, indemnify, and hold the service harmless in case of a claim related to your use of the service'
```

What I want to do is extract *ALL* `'title'` from *ALL* `points_list.keys()` and create separate json file containing key (`['tosdr/review/stackoverflow.com']`) + extracted `'title'` value. How do I construct such loop?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you expect the result to look like? Because from your question, it's not clear what you mean by "create separate json file containing key (`['tosdr/review/stackoverflow.com']`) + extracted `'title'` value"

Comment: you have to use `for`-loop to get elements from many dictionaries/lists.

Comment: This is output I am expecting ```'tosdr/review/stackoverflow.com': { 'title': 'You agree to defend, indemnify, and hold the service harmless in case of a claim related to your use of the service'}``` stackoverflow.com is a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `for`-loop to get all titles from dictionary and list

```
# get elements in dictionary
for key, value in points_list.items(): 
    # get elements in list
    for item in value:  
        print(item['title'])
```

If you want only from `[1]`

```
result = dict()

for key, value in points_list.items(): 
    result[key] = {'title': value[1]['title']}
```

or

```
result = {key:{'title': value[1]['title']} for key, value in points_list.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
def traverse_dicts( obj ) :
    if isinstance( obj, dict) :
        for k in obj :
            if k == 'title' :
                print 'title:', obj[k]
            else :
                traverse_dicts( obj[k] )
    if isinstance( obj, list) :
        for k in obj :
            traverse_dicts( k )
```

It will recursively visit all dicts / lists on all levels and print the `title` contents when found.